How to update my Python executable after modifying the source script?
I have a script in python that I turned into a .exec with PyInstaller using this line:
pyinstaller.exe --onefile <path_to_python_file>
And it worked just fine.
After that I changed my script and hoped that the executable would update itself automatically but it was not the case.
There is a way to update the .exec without deleting the old one and creating a new one from the modified script?

do you have the modified script or you want one?

Pyinstaller packages everything into the executable (you told it to do so with --onefile), so no, if you make changes, the changed .py file does not magically end up in the executable - you have to rebuild it. Technically, there may be a way to open up the archive and replace only the .py file, but it's probably less work and certainly less risky to just rebuild it.

Don't use --onfile and add the command --contents-directory="." to enable the old onedir layout without contents directory. Check the doc. Or you can downgrade PyInstaller to 5.9.0 which uses such onedir layout by default.
With this old onedir layout, you can update the file you want and no need to rebuild the exe.
pyinstaller --contents-directory="." main.py


